# How to call ViewDidAppear manually after dismiss a view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I'm having a problem with calling data from different view controller.

[image: Illustrate]

When the app is launched, it enters 1, and enters 2 immediately as 2 is the main view.
2 will then immediately check whether somebody is registered before, results as follow:

A--enter login view controller if results negative

B--call a function TO DOWNLOAD DATA in viewDidAppear as usual (which is not a problem for me now)

My problem is when A happens, users will enter his Patient ID and communicate with server and should it successfully authenticated, it will then dismiss itself and return to view controller 2.

When it returns to view controller 2, I'd expect it to run viewDidAppear and DOWNLOAD DATA as usual.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("First view appeared")
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    //if an user has logged in
    let isLoggedIn = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1){
        print("No user currently, so heading to login screen")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoLogin", sender: self)
    }else{
        print("ViewDidAppear: An user has been logged in")
        let permissionToLoadData = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN")

        if (permissionToLoadData != 1) {
            print("Please grant permission to get data")
        }else{
            print("First view: connecting to database")

            reportStatus()
            socket.connect()

            readDataFromSocket(){ data in
                let json = JSON(data)
                let nou = json[0].count
                if nou > 0 {
                    print("Test(1st VC): grabbing data from database")
                    for var i=0; i<nou; ++i{
                        numberOfUsersExisting = nou
                        pSample += [Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, gender: json[0][i]["Gender"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)]
                        pSample.sortInPlace({$0.globalPatientMileAge < $1.globalPatientMileAge})
                    }
                    print("Successfully grabbed data")
                }else{
                    print("No user in the database")
                    numberOfUsersExisting = 0
                }
            }//readDataFromSocket
        }//permission to load data
    }
}//end of viewDidAppear
```

However it didn't do what I expected, hmm, so is there anyway that I can call up viewDidAppear(from view controller 2) right after the dismiss login view controller action?

Comment: You don't.  Life cycle methods should never be called manually.

Comment: Are you actually saying that there is a way to do that but we shan't? If there is, would you mind telling how can I achieve that? :)

Comment: No.  On the off chance that at some point in the future I might have to maintain code you wrote, I won't tell you how to do things that are absurdly bad practice.

Comment: Reads like you're trying to fix the wrong problem. Have you considered doing this while leaving the pattern intact?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the downloading data logic to another method and call when you need them. So declare a function which is downloading the data.

```
let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

func downloadingData() {
    print("ViewDidAppear: An user has been logged in")
    let permissionToLoadData = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN")

    if (permissionToLoadData != 1) {
        print("Please grant permission to get data")
    }else{
        print("First view: connecting to database")

        reportStatus()
        socket.connect()

        readDataFromSocket(){ data in
            let json = JSON(data)
            let nou = json[0].count
            if nou > 0 {
                print("Test(1st VC): grabbing data from database")
                for var i=0; i<nou; ++i{
                    numberOfUsersExisting = nou
                    pSample += [Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, gender: json[0][i]["Gender"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)]
                    pSample.sortInPlace({$0.globalPatientMileAge < $1.globalPatientMileAge})
                }
                print("Successfully grabbed data")
            }else{
                print("No user in the database")
                numberOfUsersExisting = 0
            }
        }//readDataFromSocket
    }//permission to load data
}
```

Then call it on `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //if an user has logged in
    let isLoggedIn = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1){
        print("No user currently, so heading to login screen")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoLogin", sender: self)
    }else{
        downloadingData()
    }
}
```

Also when dismiss the view controller.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
    viewController.downloadingData()
}
```

Comment: Too bad I cannot do this because once viewDidLoad is ran, the data would immediately downloaded and exposed to the console before user get authenticated from the server.

Comment: Sorry, I checked the logic in more detail would you check again?

Comment: for some reason it will now authenticates as usual, but it doesn't dismiss itself at all, and the function downloadData() isn't calling out as well....